# ASynchronous exceptions throwing in Android

Tags: java, android, exception, asynchronous

I am designing an API for a network protocol, and while parsing the returned JSON I might get a few exceptions. When dealing with "regular" programming I would throw exceptions, however my API is asynchronous and callback based. This means that throwing Exceptions is out of the question.

My current solution is to pass the catched exceptions while parsing to the callback, but I fell this is not the correct way to use Exceptions in Java/Android.

What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dario Crivelli recently posted a clever solution to this problem, called the **Asynchronous Top-Down Chain pattern**.

The article is available **[here](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2014/07/exception-handling-in-asynchronous-java.html)**.

And this is the abstract:

*Hierarchical exception handling and static exception checking are among the most significant features offered by the Java language; however, their support is limited to procedural code and can only be exploited in hierarchies of function calls. So, there is nothing similar to assist us when it comes to event-driven programming or asynchronous programming, where the work is scattered among many functions that are independent from one another. This is particularly frustrating in some architectures, where the logical design is strictly hierarchical and the control flow is actually sequential, but asynchronous API calls are involved.
The present article deals with the latter case; we show how, by writing code that follows a specific pattern and leans on a suitable support library, the benefits of hierarchical exception handling and static exception checking can be achieved.*